# Querying FAST using custom FQL and Content Sources

Tags: fast-search

I am leveraging Mossman's FAST for SharePoint Query Tool, the FAST UI, and the Enterprise Search Portal to assist me in narrowing the results to a specific content source.  From my research I know the format is contentsource:Content Source Name.  I am able to get this working in the SharePoint Search portal, which does not leveral FQL.

I need to use FQL for the custom querying application I am working on.  Anyone have a working example they would be willing to share?

Alright, well after moving components around I was finally able to get the FQL to return an accurate record count.  The FQL documentation is still a bit difficult for me to pick up.  Anyone have a good resource for it besides the MSDN site?

```
<QueryText language="en-US" type="FQL">contentsource:"ContentSource1" AND string("test")</QueryText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure quite what working example you're looking for, but I suspect you want the c# to fire off an FQL query. If so, I don't have anything handy.

If by chance you're just looking for the FQL then something like the following will work (just type your FQL into the QR-Server).

```
contentsource:'Content'
```

Comment: Yes, I even referenced that above.  But where does that go in the FQL text?  For instance, lets say I am hitting a document library with the name WorkSite Atlanta searching for the word "test".  I know that the FQL is string("test", Mode="AND).  Where does the Content Source part go?

Comment: You've already marked as answered, but I think you're looking for something like and(name:'WorkSite Atlanta', contentsource:'Content'). I don't tend to do much FQL but will need to later this evening for work so will post my findings.

Comment: or(propertyname:"propertyvalue1",propertyname2:"propertyvalue2")

Comment: and(propertyname:"propertyvalue1",propertyname2:"propertyvalue2")

Comment: THE FQL snippet I posted above works for me.